# Having issues broadcasting BitcoinJS transaction.

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, bitcoinjs

I'm trying to send testnet with bitcoinjs, but when I go to broadcast the hex, it gives me an error code that says "fee is too high: 12372928". Now, from my understanding, the fee is the input - output. However, even if I increase the output to match the wallet's balance, I get the same exact error message. Here's my code:

```
        this.setState({
            address: 'mphWVWbPgGKuaMpSpGNA3Ffrpva5cRChqP',
            privateKey: 'cW6dLEqkk2HAbQTSJaHnn4w3kd2iJfhBREccEE3vzrq8kcVE5TqS',
        });      
}

createTransaction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {address, privateKey} = this.state;
    var hashURL = `https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/addrs/${address}`


        axios.get(hashURL).then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                hash: response.data.txrefs[0].tx_hash
            })
        }).then((result) => {

        var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(testnet);

        var txId = this.state.hash;

        console.log(txId);

        tx.addInput(txId, 0)

        tx.addOutput(this.state.add, 1000000)

        var keyPair2 = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF(privateKey, testnet);

        tx.sign(0, keyPair2);
        console.log(tx.build().toHex());
        }
    )

}
```

Would there be a way to manually set the fee to always be something like .0001?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The miner fee will, by default, equal the inputs - outputs of your transaction.
I notice some problems with your code. You do not specify a change address to send the left-over amount. If I have an unspent output of `100` BTC and I want to send `10` BTC to someone else, I should have 1 input (the unspent output from the previous transaction) and 2 outputs (the receiver address and the change address). The inputs and outputs will look like this:

**Inputs**

- Unspent output of `100` BTC

**Outputs**

- Receiver address with `10` BTC
- Change address (your BTC address) with `89.999` BTC

The fee will be `0.001` BTC since `(in)(100) - (out)(10 + 89.999) = 0.001`.
Hope I was able to help.